# Background image does not appear on mac

Tags: image, osx

I am trying to insert an image in the 3D View (Background image, Dropped image, Images as planes).
Whatever the technique, I get an empty yellow rectangle.
I know there has been lots of posts on this subject: I already tried to change the views, and to toggle between Perspective and orthogonal view, but neither succeed.

I have to specify that I am working on MacOS.
I tried today on a PC and it worked very well.

Does anybody have a suggestion?

[image]

Comment: please provide your blend file. I have a mac. I can check it out.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be your issue but,  in your example, at the top right,  in **viewport shading** you have solid shading. You must select the material preview, or rendered mode.

Comment: I tried his, but still not works. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I was working in the layout workspace. By changing to the modeling workspace, I can finally see my images.